# model rewrite not working in admin side

Tags: overrides, model, class, fedex

i have  rewritten fedex.php model file(collect rates method  only).

its working in front end cart and checkout pages.
But its not working in admin side order creation.Can you help any one?

**update**:

I added one custom product drop-down  attribute(special_shipping_group).

If at least one product contain option "Free 2nd Day Shipping" in cart items then FEDEX_2_DAY method price should be zero.

**Step1:** Rewrite class is

```
class Exinent_Freefedexshipping_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex extends Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex {

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
        $originalResult = parent::collectRates($request);
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $flag = false;
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($product->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getAttributeText('special_shipping_group') == "Free 2nd Day Shipping") {
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($flag) {
            foreach ($originalResult->getAllRates() as $method) {
                if ($method->getmethod() == "FEDEX_2_DAY") {
                    $method->setPrice(0);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->getResult();
    }
```

Step2:Create config.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Exinent_Freefedexshipping>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Exinent_Freefedexshipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
       <exinent_freefedexshipping>
       <class>Exinent_Freefedexshipping_Model</class>
       </exinent_freefedexshipping>
          <usa>
            <rewrite>
       <shipping_carrier_fedex>Exinent_Freefedexshipping_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex</shipping_carrier_fedex>
            </rewrite>
          </usa>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step3: Module global config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Exinent_Freefedexshipping>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Exinent_Freefedexshipping>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing brace in your class, is that just a typo?

Comment: I added additional details.Can you any one  remove "on hold".please let me know if i miss anything.and my problem solved also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get frontend quote

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
```

To get Backend quote

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
```

Therefore you need those check if you are on the frontend or admin

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()
```

Try

```
....
$originalResult = parent::collectRates($request);

if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()){
   $cart = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
}
else{
   $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
}

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
....
```

see

- [Magento Request - Frontend or Backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693020/magento-request-frontend-or-backend)